# installing and deploying ranking scripts in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, gradle, elasticsearch-plugin

I have written a elastic search scoring script plugin in java with a similar structure as https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-native-script-example and have made a zip file using gradle assemble which is present in build/distributions folder. I am using elastic search 2.4 version.

I am trying to install the plugin into elastic search by

```
./bin/plugin install file:/full/path/to/elasticsearch-native-script-example-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

but I get the following error

```
ERROR: Plugin [elasticsearch-native-script-example] must be at least a jvm or site plugin
```

The plugin-descriptor.properties file which is auto generated does not contain jvm=true,

How to modify the project to specify jvm=true in plugin-descriptor.properties. Please advise.

Comment: Have you verified that you follow the official rules for plugin authors available at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.4/plugin-authors.html ?

Comment: yes, I am using exactly the same .zip file which is generated by gradle assemble https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-native-script-example. I tried installing it on ES 2.1 also but this gives the same error. Thanks.

Comment: I just realized that the plugin-descriptor.properties file which is auto generated does not contain jvm=true, how do I modify the project to specify the same.